# Universal object cloning solution

Tags: ruby, clone

I need a universal cloning solution to deep clone a module with all its instance variables in Ruby. I can't really use `.clone` method, since it doesn't work on activerecord objects (doesn't copy the id field).

I also saw a workaround by using marshal dump + marshal load, but it doesn't work on module and singleton objects. Does anyone know any solution to deep clone a module? Or maybe you have another solution for my real problem.

I have a module with instance variables set and I need to clone it to another module, modify objects in the cloned object, then clone the first module again without having changes made by the second module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dup` instead of `clone` for ActiveRecord objects, but dup doesn't copy singleton methods(defined on objects) + it changes frozen state to tainted one.

As for Rails also you have the [Deep cloning](http://github.com/DefV/deep_cloning) plugin for ActiveRecord cloning.